# python flask passing excel doc with drop down filter

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I am new to Flask.I am trying to read a excel file use one of its columns as drop down list as filter to display 2 columns. when i run the code i get a internal server error message:
    Please help me debug this code
    below is my code

```
# Create your views here.
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/getfields',methods=['GET','POST'])
def getfields(request):
    df = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\mysite\Rules.xls')
    allfields = df['Field_Name'].unique()
    if request.method == 'GET':

        return render_template('page1.html',allfields=allfields)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        dropValue = request.form.get(['fieldnames'])
        dfrows = df.loc[df['Field_Name']==dropValue]
        return render_template('page1.html',allfields=allfields,dfrows=dfrows[['rule','rule_type']].to_html())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()



html code:
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Hello from Flask</title>
    <h1>Hello {{ allfields }}!</h1>
    <form action="/getfields" method='post'> 

    <select name='fieldnames'>
    {% for val in allfields %}
    <option value='{{val}}'>{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
             
    </select> 
    {{dfrows}}
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
```

Comment: Run your application in debug mode (`app.run(debug=True)`), so that whenever there is an error you get a detailed stack trace.

Comment: the error says:"GET /getfields HTTP/1.1" 404-

Comment: Can't be. An "Internal Service Error" has a code 500, it's either 500 or 404. You are looking at something different now.

Comment: I ran again the code got the below error:

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?